# how to clear checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to clear the selection of checkboxes if they click cancel. How can I achive this with this code:

```
var chkbox= $('#divListBox').find(':checked')
                 .map(function() {
                     return $(this).val();
                 }).get();
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#divListBox :checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: `$(this).removeAttr('checked');` is prettier, methinks. +1

Comment: As far as I know jQuery can apply a function on a collection of elements, so the following will work as well: 
    $('#divListBox').find(':checked').attr('checked', '');

Comment: If you want pretty, I'd remove the `.find()` and the `.each()` and do something more like this: `$('#divListBox :checked').removeAttr('checked');` :o)

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this solution is if you have on change events or on click events tied to the checkbox this will make them happen.

```
$('#divListBox').each(function(index, element) {
  var checked = element.checked;
  if (checked) {
    $(element).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Also with bootstrap the checkbox wasn't getting found with the `:checked` selector.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged the question with `jquery` but not explicitly mentioned that you only want to use jquery, so...

`document.getElementById("divListBox").checked = false;`

Frankly I only use jquery when it helps.